# building SMSPopup

Tags: android

Did anyone successfully build an application using [SMSPopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/) ?

Firstly, I use the command `android.bat update project -p <source code path>`
Then I run `ant debug` to build the project.
Here is the error meessage I get.

I know something wrong with the dependency of `Android-ViewPagerIndicator`.
However, I couldn't know how to do it.
Can anyone advice. Thanks!

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Buildfile: C:\Users\michael\workspace\android-smspopup\SMSPopup\build.xml

-set-mode-check:
-set-debug-files:
-set-debug-mode:
-debug-obfuscation-check:
-setup:
     [echo] Gathering info for SmsPopupConfigActivity...
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 15
    [setup] Project Target: Android 4.0
    [setup] API level: 14
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] C:\Users\michael\workspace\android-smspopup\SMSPopup: ../../git/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library => C:\Users\michael\workspace\git\Android-ViewPagerIndicator\library
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Ordered libraries:
    [setup] C:\Users\michael\workspace\git\Android-ViewPagerIndicator\library
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] 
    [setup] WARNING: Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml (7) is lower than the project target API level (14)

-build-setup:
     [echo] Building Libraries

C:\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:466: Invalid file: C:\Users\michael\workspace \git\Android-ViewPagerIndicator\library\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```